# IOS Location - didUpdateLocations not called

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am trying to get location. Issue is that
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) and locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) are never called.

I am asked for permission. I grant it. When I call startLocation second time:

```
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let gpsController = GPSController()
        gpsController.startLocation()
        
        sleep(10)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                gpsController.startLocation()
            }
    }
```

I can see that permission is granted.

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class GPSController : NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

let locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
static var lastLocation : CLLocation? = nil


func startLocation(){
    locationManager.delegate = self
    
    // Sprawdź status usług lokalizacyjnych
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        switch locationManager.authorizationStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            print("notDetermined")
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            break
        case .restricted, .denied:
            print("Denied")
            break
        case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            print("authorizedWhenInUse")
        case .authorized:
            print("authorized")
            break
        @unknown default:
            print("@unknown")
            break
        }
    } else {
        print("turn off")
    }
    
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    print("didChangeAuthorization")
    if manager.authorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print("didChangeAuthorization")
    for currentLocation in locations{
        Loge("Location : \(currentLocation)")
        GPSController.lastLocation = currentLocation
    }
}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("error")
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting `GPSController` inside a global queue, so the scope of the controller does not escape from the queue. After the queue is executed, the controller will be removed. And it no longer listens to that `delegate`. You can check it by `deinit`, it will print out after `sleep(10)`.

```swift
class GPSController : NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    deinit {
        print("Released")
    }
}
```

To resolve: put the `GPSController`, i.e within a class/controller, to keep a reference.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let gpsController = GPSController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            gpsController.startLocation()

            sleep(10)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                gpsController.startLocation()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Btw, the delegate should be assigned once, so I would prefer to put it in `init`

```swift
convenience init() {
    self.init()
    locationManager.delegate = self
}
```